# How do I get video dimensions from a video url in python?

Tags: python, video

I need to get the video dimensions of some videos using there urls on python. Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests:

```
import requests

def get_video_size(url):
    response = requests.head(url)
    size_in_bytes = int(response.headers.get('Content-Length', 0))
    size_in_mb = size_in_bytes / (1024 * 1024)
    return size_in_mb

# Usage
video_url = "https://example.com/video.mp4"
size = get_video_size(video_url)
print(f"Video size: {size:.2f} MB")
```

This code sends a "HEAD" request to retrieve the headers of the video URL and then extracts the "Content-Length" field. It also converts the size from bytes to megabytes for convenience.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the `pafy` library:

```
import pafy 
    
url = "https://www.youtube.com / watch?v = **id**"

video = pafy.new(url) 
  
streams = video.allstreams
  
stream = streams[7]
  
value = stream.dimensions

print("Dimension : " + str(value))
```

Stream is basically the available resolution of the video.